# How to deploy multiple copies of same application on Glassfish server?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish, application-server

I have a war and an ejb deployed on my Glassfish V3. I need to deploy another copies of these for testing purpose, how I do I go about this?

I am sorry, if this question looks too general, but am not sure what words to use here as I have never done this before.

I just need some directions to get started.

**Update:**

What I was actually trying to see was if it was possible to deploy two copies of the same application with the same name and same application-context but access them from two different ports as follows -

localhost:8080/MyApp and localhost:8181/MyApp

Comment: I haven't tried this either, but have you tried uploading the same .ear and giving it a different application name?

Comment: @KublaiKhan: I was thinking that may be I was supposed to create a new instance or open a new port or may be new virtual server. What are those for?

Comment: Give them different names when you build the ear, like project-development, project-test, and project.  Most people put up development and test Glassfish servers for this reason.

Comment: @Gilbert Le Blanc: On the same machine?

Comment: You can put your development and test Glassfish servers on the same machine, just give them different ports.  Your production Glassfish server should stand alone.  You don't want your production server coming down because someone did something in the development or test environments.

Comment: @Gilbert Le Blanc: Can it be done with MySql too?

Comment: I believe so, just assign a different port to the second installation of MySQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multiple **domains** was what I actually needed.

Answer (score 2):

Give the three copies different application context names

[edit]

I just installed Glassfish 3, and deployed two copies of Jenkins through the glassfish admin console, each with a different war name. I gave each one a different context and different application name and now have two copies running.

[image]

Comment: I was thinking that may be I was supposed to create a new instance or open a new port or may be new virtual server. What are those for?

Comment: @BheshGurung - You're right, it looks like it can't deploy a second application from the same .war regardless of the specified name. +1 to your question. I even tried different builds.

Comment: @KublaiKhan: Thank you. I hope somebody will come across this question who has done or knows how to.